# How to pass access token in server.js in React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have a react app. For all api calls i am able to attach access token in headers since i have the token in app context. there are other api calls in server.js file which does not have access token. How can i pass access token in header.

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const httpPort = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const httpsPort = 3443;
const server = express();

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const ENVS = {
    development: 'dev',
    staging: 'uat',
    production: 'app'
};
const mockServer = !!process.env.MOCK_SERVER;
const mockPort = parseInt(process.env.MOCK_PORT, 10) || 3001;
const mockBaseUrl = process.env.MOCK_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost';

const protocol = 'https://';
const domain = 'cloud.virtana.com';
/* to use staging apis use ENVS.staging or ENVS.production to use prod apis  */
const environment = process.env.USE_ENV || ENVS.production;
const URL = protocol + environment + '.' + domain;
const GRAPH_QL = `${protocol}api.${process.env.USE_ENV}.optimize.virtana.com`

console.log('file: server.js; process.env.USE_ENV --> ', process.env.USE_ENV);

const devProxy = {
    '/sso/saml/acs': {
        target: mockServer ? mockBaseUrl + ':' + mockPort + '/api' : URL + '/authentication/sso/saml/acs',
        pathRewrite: { '^/authentication/sso/saml/acs/': '' },
        changeOrigin: dev,
        secure: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
    },
    '/api/v1': {
        target: mockServer ? mockBaseUrl + ':' + mockPort + '/api/v1' : URL + '/constellation/api/v1',
        pathRewrite: { '^/api/v1': '' },
        secure: true,
        changeOrigin: dev,
        logLevel: 'debug',
    },
 }
 
 
 
 
 const app = next({
    dir: '.', // base directory where everything is, could move to src later
    dev: true,
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    Object.keys(devProxy).forEach(function (context) {
        server.use(createProxyMiddleware(context, devProxy[context]));
    });
    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
    });

    http.createServer(server).listen(httpPort, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(`> Ready on port ${httpPort}`);
    });

    if (dev) {
        https.createServer({
            key: fs.readFileSync('cert/vcio.key'),
            cert: fs.readFileSync('cert/vcio.crt'),
        }, server).listen(httpsPort, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(`> Ready on secure port ${httpsPort}`);
        });
    }
})
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('An error occurred, unable to start the server -> ', err);
    });
```

I need to pass access token to '/api/v1' and '/sso/saml/acs'

I am not able to access my appcontext in server.js file. So I need to somehow get access token in this server.js file and attach that in authorization header.